# Correct way to transform AngularJS from my node_modules folder

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

I have chosen to use `npm` to include my UI dependencies like AngularJS.

After the installation the dependencies exist in the `node_modules` folder.

I can use AngularJS directly using `<script src='/node_modules/angular/etc.'></script>`

In reality, what I want to do is transform it as part of my gulp tasks, and move (minify/uglify if nescessary) to my assets folder.

What is the correct way to do this? How do I find all the dependent libraries, is this a manual include or is there a better way?

My gulp task looks like:

```
gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    gulp.src(["js/**/*.js", "!" + "js/**/*.min.js"], { base: "." })
        .pipe(concat("assets/js/site.min.js"))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
```

Comment: This is a good start https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/08/angularjs-browserify/. Also i would recommend you to explore webpack and gulp-webpack

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be on the right track with using Gulp, however, you'll soon realize that not using a bundler will be a bit more difficult that you want it to be if you are new to this approach.  I believe you will benefit from using a loader like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/).  Both of these will allow you to combine all of your client dependencies into bundles as you see fit.  These libraries will let you to use AMD and/or CommonJS to "require" your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly not using yeoman and bower, not that there's anything wrong in NOT using it.

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

http://yeoman.io/codelab/

Have a look at Yeoman generators, in particular "generator-angular". This will setup (scaffold) your angular project for you based on some (accepted) best practices. And utilizes bower to manage your client side dependencies. Gulp is then (automatically configured) used to build/include/bundle the dependencies.

My suggestion is to install yeoman, and check the "generator-angular" generator, and then look at how gulp manages the building of the dependencies from the bower components.

I.e. once you use something like a yeoman generator, most of the work is done for you, i.e. yeoman generator solves this particular problem of your with very little to no effort.